# I am trying to install RStudio on my Ubuntu system (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)

Tags: rstudio

I am running the command `sudo dpkg -i /Downloads/rstudio-2023.09.1-494-amd64.deb`. Can someone help me fix this? Is there a way to individually install the libssl packages?

```
Selecting previously unselected package rstudio.
(Reading database ... 207329 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rstudio-2023.09.1-494-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rstudio (2023.09.1+494) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rstudio:
 rstudio depends on libssl1.0.0 | libssl1.0.2 | libssl1.1; however:
  Package libssl1.0.0 is not installed.
  Package libssl1.0.2 is not installed.
  Package libssl1.1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package rstudio (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rstudio
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve library dependancy for Rstudio in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404233/how-to-solve-library-dependancy-for-rstudio-in-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, unfortunately it did not work for my system. I will just wait till the new update is available and then try re-installing it.

Comment: It works - but you need to navigate the website - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

From [this linked answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404233/how-to-solve-library-dependancy-for-rstudio-in-ubuntu-22-04), it actually points to [dailies.rstudio.com](https://dailies.rstudio.com/), which has the latest .Deb packages for various platforms.

The latest build of Rstudio 2023.09 is [rstudio-2023.09.2-508-amd64.deb](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-ide-build/electron/jammy/amd64/rstudio-2023.09.2-508-amd64.deb).

I just downloaded and did a test run (`apt install --dry-run`), and it seems to install with no issue on Ubuntu 22.04.

There's also Rstudio 2023.12 with the build [rstudio-2023.12.0-363-amd64.deb](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-ide-build/electron/jammy/amd64/rstudio-2023.12.0-363-amd64.deb), which also did the simulated installation fine.

So I still believe the duplicate gives the answer, although you of course have to correctly navigate the website it links to.